# Connected to Router with WLAN stick but no Internet

Tags: wireless, networking

similarly to this post

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2125952&highlight=11n_disable

that is, I dont get any internet traffic while being a connected to the router. I am using a wlan stick (wlan1) instead of the built in wifi chip (wlan0) to get a better connection. The built in chip is working, but when switching to the wlan stick, I get a very good conection but no traffic.

Here is the output of the script that was posted in the above mentioned post:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/26724910/wireless-info.txt

I highly apprechiate any ideas of how to resolve this problem.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Could the line `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in your resolv.conf cause the problem? See [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/327532/why-would-127-0-0-1-in-resolv-conf-cause-problems-in-dns-resolution), first answer, bullet 4.

Comment: Both internal and usb adaptor are on at the same time thet is probably an issue. We may be able to get your internal card to work better if you would like to try? or disable it completely and see if that help you connect with the usb adaptor? If you think the usb adaptor is going to be faster it probably will not if we work on the internal device, it may show a higher rate but actually loading pages from the web and download apps it will probably still be about the same.

Comment: thanks for all the answers! Disabling 11n at the router resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could type the following in the terminal:

```
nmap -v -iR 10000 -Pn -p 80
```

To see if there is a soft block, enter:

```
rfkill list
```

To see if it is connected, enter:

```
lspci
```

And then in the terminal type:

```
lsmod wlan0
```

And then type in the terminal:

```
lsusb -S wlan0
```

It should work fine this way.