# Very slow DNS lookup

Tags: 16.04, networking, network-manager, dns

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, and when I visit a website/curl/wget/ping/etc anything that isn't an IP address, it takes an annoyingly long time (> 5 s), whereas anything directly using an IP address is pretty much instant (< 10 ms, as one would expect).

When I `cat /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`, I get:

```
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false
```

I've tried changing to `#dns=dnsmasq`, but it didn't have any noticeable effect.

`cat /etc/network/interfaces` is also quite basic:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

A bit odd is `cat /etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 10.63.240.10
nameserver 127.0.1.1
search $companydomain$.com
```

The `nameserver 10.63.240.10` is something a colleague doesn't have, and is the only way in which the above 3 files differ for us.
I suspect that is the root of the issue, because when I do `host www.stackexchange.com 10.63.240.10`, I get:

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

Commenting it out and restarting the network-manager fixes the issue temporarily, only to return upon rebooting.

I've also noticed in the Network Connections menu, two (seemingly) auto-generated Bridge entries are listed: `br-8f98800bd128` and `br-bd749c12d64c`.
If I delete these, they're back after a reboot. My aforementioned colleague doesn't have these either.

I've also tried the suggestions from [How do I configure my DNS settings in Ubuntu server?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/346838/how-do-i-configure-my-dns-settings-in-ubuntu-server) and [Extrememly slow DNS lookup](https://askubuntu.com/questions/272358/extrememly-slow-dns-lookup/272574#272574), but the issue remains.

Per [M. Becerra](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041526/very-slow-dns-lookup#comment1696681_1041526)'s suggestion, I ran `sudo updatedb; locate 10.63.240.10`. This didn't give me any output.

[Mikael Schultz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041526/very-slow-dns-lookup#comment1696936_1041526) suggested I do `nmcli device show`, which outputs:

```
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-8f98800bd128
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:50:5E:58:3B
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     br-8f98800bd128
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.18.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         br-bd749c12d64c
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         02:42:B1:85:6D:E3
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     br-bd749c12d64c
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.19.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         docker0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           bridge
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         36:CA:3D:66:B7:03
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     docker0
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.17.0.1/16
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlp3s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:28:F8:9C:2A:4D
GENERAL.MTU:                            0
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Crowdynews
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/0
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         10.0.0.27/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            10.0.0.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             8.8.8.8
IP4.DNS[2]:                             8.8.4.4
IP4.DOMAIN[1]:                          crowdynews.com
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::9264:b967:1c59:3e50/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp4s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         C8:5B:76:F1:1C:EC
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:
```

`ip address` prints:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
link/ether c8:5b:76:f1:1c:ec brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
link/ether 00:28:f8:9c:2a:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 10.0.0.27/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic wlp3s0
   valid_lft 1660731sec preferred_lft 1660731sec
inet6 fe80::9264:b967:1c59:3e50/64 scope link 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 02:42:f3:cd:08:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.17.0.1/16 brd 172.17.255.255 scope global docker0
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: br-8f98800bd128: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 02:42:50:5e:58:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global br-8f98800bd128
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
6: br-bd749c12d64c: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
link/ether 02:42:b1:85:6d:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
inet 172.19.0.1/16 brd 172.19.255.255 scope global br-bd749c12d64c
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN

nameserver 10.63.240.10
```

`cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base` generates no output.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Try to change to a name server like `8.8.8.8` - Side note: https://whois.domaintools.com/10.63.240.10

Comment: I've tried adding a line with `dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8` in /etc/network/interfaces, but that didn't fix it, because `10.63.240.10` was still tried first.

Comment: Please comment out the original name server to let `8.8.8.8` be used

Comment: Where? Removing `nameserver 10.63.240.10` from `/etc/resolv.conf` and then manually restarting the network-manager only works temporarily. It's back after a reboot. I can't find where it keeps coming from, but it always returns.

Comment: Done. It didn't give me any output...

Comment: Sorry I meant `sudo grep -r "10.63.240.10" /*`.Also try to comment out the current name server at `/etc/resolv.conf` by editing it like this `# nameserver 10.63.240.10` and then append `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

Comment: As mentioned, commenting out `nameserver 10.63.240.10` from `/etc/resolv.conf` seems to work, but a reboot reinstates the problem.

Comment: Could you edit your answer with the output of the command `nmcli device show`? And also the output of the command `ip address`.

Comment: Of course. See above for edits. :)

Comment: Nice, but it looks okay to me. Can you also insert the output of `cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` and `cat /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/base`?

Comment: I've added both. `resolv.conf.d/base` is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem seems to be that there is a faulty DNS server in the file `/etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head`.

Edit the `head` file and delete the line that says `nameserver 10.63.240.10` and you should have solved your problem.

Run `sudo nano /etc/resolvconf/resolv.conf.d/head` from the Terminal to edit the file and make sure that the only content of the file is:

```
# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file for glibc resolver(3) generated by resolvconf(8)
#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It seems your suggestion worked. Should this be a permanent solution? Because it even says in the file any modifications will be overwritten. I've rebooted, but that didn't seem to restore the file to the version with `nameserver 10.63.240.10`, so DNS requests are still quick. :) Do you have any idea where the custom DNS server might've come from? As far as I know, I haven't set it myself, and I'm the only one who's installed anything on this laptop. Could it have been set by some network settings?

Comment: I would consider it a permanent solution. If it isn’t I’m sure someone will object :) It should not have been there in the first place and I have no idea how it got there. These (head and base) are the files that will be the source of the file /etc/resolv.conf when it is generated, that is why the text is saying that modifications will be overwritten.

Comment: Aha, so the `#     DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE BY HAND -- YOUR CHANGES WILL BE OVERWRITTEN` line is only in the `/etc/resolv.conf.d/head` file so it finds its way into the regular `/etc/resolv.conf` file? Thanks!

Comment: Yes that is my understanding. No problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Meybe this can help someone (THE PROBLEM IS THE DOCKER). I had the same problem on **UBUNTU 22.04**, after a long time changing network related configs the solutions was.

```
docker network prune
```

I had a lot of docker networks and this was causing a slow DNS Lookup (I could reach some sites and others was giving timeout)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. To solve it, I changed my DNS server settings and now everything gets resolved really fast (apt update, Firefox startup, git, etc.).

**Change DNS server settings**:

If you are using a wired network, go to Ubuntu Settings > Network > Wired > Options > IPv4. Make sure IPv4 Method is Automatic (DHCP) and choose your DNS server (I personally use https://1.1.1.1/dns/). You can do the same for IPv6, make sure to put a valid IPv6 to the DNS server.

[image: wired config]

If you are using a Wireless connection, go to Ubuntu Settings > Wireless > [YourWifi] > Options and follow the same instructions.

Comment: OP seems to like using terminal, the equivalent way is [using `nmtui` (NetworkManager TUI)](https://askubuntu.com/a/1174193/349837)